# Courtesy pings should be deletable by their targets

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies, comment-flags

If a comment says only

```
([cC]ourtesy\s)?[pP]ing(:|-|,|ing|\s|to|for)*@[^\s]+
```

or

```
@[^\s]+\s*([cC]ourtesy\s)?[pP]ing.{0,2}
```

(or something like that), then the person identified in the database as its "ReplyTo User" should be allowed to delete it, and if he flags it as obsolete, then that flag should be immediately effective instead of queued.

Comment: I suspect most of the answers to this will be: "don't courtesy ping".

Comment: That is a good idea. Don't know if it's a feasible idea, but it's a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: +1 Definitely can help clean up the comment threads without burdening the mods.

Comment: How often is this used?  (I've never seen it.)  Better yet, how often is it used compared to how often people are pinged for the same purpose using other words?  (Does it cover the majority of cases?  Is it worth doing?)

Comment: @MatthewRead, it's definitely used, but how often it's used versus courtesy pings using other strings (e.g. `@foo, also.`) is a valuable question whose answer I don't know. OTOH, if this becomes the standard, then people can be encouraged to use it when necessary.

Comment: Nice idea, but I often see people not delete *their own* obsolete comments even when their peers write something like *"@name, I cleaned up my comments"* or *"let's clean up our comments"*. Hence, I doubt many users would actually exercise any option to clean up comments directed to them.

Comment: Actually msh210, it seems from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=courtesy+ping&sitesearch=meta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22courtesy+ping%22+site:meta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions&oq=%22courtesy+ping%22+site:meta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...7365.8660.0.8886.2.2.0.0.0.0.55.110.2.2.0...0.0.FMxPO4XUwpo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3a06c9010a32a30&biw=1304&bih=707) that you are the only person to use this convention.

Comment: @DoubleAA, with "courtesy", anyway, and *if* Google's accurate. Maybe I'm [projecting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection).

Comment: @MatthewRead Well, if it became a feature I imagine people would start using it; the actual regex isn't really important

Comment: "@username ^^^" is a variant I've seen fairly often (though I've seen it in both comments and chat and I don't know what proportion is specifically comments).

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly like this. Not everyone headers the ping as a "courtesy ping", and then this would just add to our growing list of hidden functionality. And regexes only go so far...

Instead, how about a "courtesy ping" flag reason?

Comment: ...there's a flag limit for moderators?

Comment: @arjan hmm, why did I write _that_? I think 10k have a limit, but they can't delete anyway.